# Sort titles in Array of objects with VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to sort my array of objects. I have managed to use the console to return all the titles but struggling now to perform the actual sort. I am using a select menu to switch between relevancy (default) and to sort alphabetically.

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
 <select v-model="sortatoz" v-on:change="sortItems($event)">
              <option disabled value="">Select</option>
              <option value="alphabetically">Alphabetically</option>
              <option value="relevance">Relevance</option>
            </select>




 methods: {
        sortItems: function sortItems(event) {
          this.sortby = event.target.value;
          if (this.sortatoz === "alphabetically") {
            Array.from(
              document.querySelectorAll("div > h3.title")
            ).map((x) => x.innerText);
           ??What should I add here to sort???
          } else {
            Array.from(
              document.querySelectorAll("div > h3.title")
            ).map((x) => x.innerText);
            ???
          }
        },
```

Comment: Are your `h3.title` elements the result of a `v-for` loop? if so just manipulate the arary.

Comment: Would it be possible to give an example of the code?

Comment: @user13928344 You can checkout https://github.com/Jebasuthan/vue_crud_bootstrap for more vue features implemented in the application with demo

Comment: I will check this out too, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Step 1:*** Create `HTML` template with `select` options and `table` to display data with sorting functionality.

```
 <div id="app">
  <select v-model="sortatoz" @change="sortItems">
    <option disabled value="">Select</option>
    <option value="alphabetically">Alphabetically</option>
    <option value="relevance">Relevance</option>
  </select>
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Authur</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item, index) in sortedItems" :key="index">
        <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.authur }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

***Step 2:*** Define your `model` data. I created a sample model `data` with books `title` with `Authur` names

```
 data() {
  return {
    sortatoz: "",
    listTitles: [
      {
        title: "Cabbages and Kings",
        authur: "O. Henry",
      },
      {
        title: "Alien Corn",
        authur: "Sidney Howard",
      },
      {
        title: "The Little Foxes",
        authur: "Lillian Hellman",
      },
      {
        title: "A Time of Gifts",
        authur: "Patrick Leigh Fermor",
      },
      {
        title: "Ego Dominus Tuus",
        authur: "W. B. Yeats",
      },
      {
        title: "Antic Hay",
        authur: "Aldous Huxley",
      },
    ],
  };
},
```

***Step 3:*** Define your `computed` lifecycle. When ever changes happened in the `model` data automatically `computed` function will get updated.

```
computed: {
  sortedItems() {
    return this.listTitles;
  },
},
```

***Step 4:*** Define `@change` event for `select` options

```
 methods: {
  sortItems() {
    if (this.sortatoz === "alphabetically") {
      return this.listTitles.sort((a, b) => (a.title > b.title ? 1 : -1));
    } else {
      return this.listTitles.sort((a, b) => (a.title > b.title ? -1 : 1));
    }
  },
},
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-wind-u4dh0)

Comment: Thank you so much. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user13928344 Its my pleasure! You can checkout github.com/Jebasuthan/vue_crud_bootstrap Table sorting, filter, search and Pagination are implemented with localStorage, Vuex, Vue routing, REST API  call, custom component creation, Validations are all implemented.

Comment: I will do that, thank you!